# Why do I have both HTTPS and HTTP links on site, need them all secure!

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, oscommerce

I am getting the security alert: "You are about to be directed to a connection that is not secure. the information you are sending to the current site might be transmitted to a non-secure site. Do you wish to continue?" when I try to login as a customer on my clients oscommerce website. I noticed the link in the status bar goes from a https prefix to a nonsecure http prefix. The site has a SSL certificate, so how do I ensure the entire store portion of the site directs to the secured site?

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that some parts of the page, most often images or scripts, are loaded non-secure. You'll need to go through them in the browser's "view page source" view one by one and eliminate the reason (most often, a configuration setting pointing to `http://`).

Some external tools like Google Analytics that you may be embedding on your site can be included through `https://`, some don't. In that case, you may have to remove those tools from your secure site.

If you can't switch all the settings, try using relative paths

```
<img src="/images/shop/xyz.gif">
```

but the first thing is to identify the non-secure elements using the source code view of your browser.

An immediate redirection from a `https://` page to a `http:/` one would not result in a warning as you describe. Can you specify what's up with that?

Comment: Sure, if you go to https://balancedecosolutions.com/products//catalog/login.php and login as a customer. I have setup someone@somewhere.com as the user name and test123 as the password. You'll see the message (IE6) when you try to login.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the following are included over https:

- css files
- js files
- embedded media (images, videos)

If you're confident none of your own stuff is included over http, check things like tracking pixels and other third-party gadgets.

Edit: Now that you've linked your page, I see that your `<base>` tag is the problem:

```
<base href="http://balancedecosolutions.com/products//catalog/">
```

Change to:

```
<base href="https://balancedecosolutions.com/products//catalog/">
```

Comment: Thanks shark... the only reference to that that I can find is a line of code like this: <base href="<?php echo (($request_type == 'SSL') ? HTTPS_SERVER : HTTP_SERVER) . DIR_WS_CATALOG; ?>">

Comment: Hopefully the OSCommerce software has an option for always using `HTTPS_SERVER`. If not, try editing that line:

`<base href="<?php echo HTTPS_SERVER . DIR_WS_CATALOG; ?>">`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and browse your site, in the listing it should become evident what is using HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Jon Galloway talks about this in one of his blog-posts: 

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2009/10/15/did-you-know-about-protocol-relative-hyperlinks.aspx

TL;DR - pre-pend it with // rather than http(s)

Answer (score 1):

If the suggestion from Pekka doesn't suit your needs you can try using relative links based on the *schema* (http or https):

e.g.,

```
<a href="//www.example.com/mypage.html">I am a 100% valid link!</a>
```

The only problem with this technique is that it doesn't work with CSS files in all browsers; though it does work within Javascript and inline CSS. (I could be wrong here; anyone want to check?).

e.g., the following :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycss.css" />
<!-- mycss.css contents: -->
...
body{
    background-image:url(//static.example.com/background.png);
}
...
```

...might fail.

A simple Find/Replace on your source code could be easy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the HTML form you are submitting is hardcoded to post to a non-secure page.