# ssl showing error in website

Tags: javascript, django, ssl, youtube

In my website, there is an error occurred based on the ssl. On the main page, there is a  youtube video will play, when the site load. I think the ssl error is due to this because after inspecting element, it shows the following error:

1) Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://dev.myproject.info/ from frame with URL https://www.youtube.com/embed/Zr4JwPb99qU?autoplay=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

2) The page at https://dev.myproject.info/ displayed insecure content from http://r4---sn-ci5gup-h55e.googlevideo.com/crossdomain.xml.

3) The page at https://dev.myproject.info/ displayed insecure content from http://r4---sn-ci5gup-h55e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?algorithm=throttle-factor&burst=40&clen=1704783&cpn=LbUqMfNNay39Ml-

I don't know what to do. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too would love to see google fix this. Even when you put the video in with https it still gets it's crossdomain.xml files and a few other files from an http source. Very lame of google. I even found a question about it in their google code forums and google closed it from responses.

Answer (score 1):

The first warning you can't get rid off, it always shows up if an iframe tries to access data from another iframe not hosted from the same domain. It happens with a lot of third-party content (like a LinkedIn button on your site for example) since you can't check if you have access without triggering the warning. But you can safely ignore it as it won't show up to end users.

As for the other two, as this data is loaded by the youtube iframe which you don't have control over you can't get rid of it. I think this has only started happening recently and Google/Youtube will have to fix it on their end. I guess the only solution for now is to open videos in another window (which isn't really ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I actually went through something similar with my JQUERY link for HTTPS/SSL.

> Originally it was:  "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
>
> Then I changed it to this: "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"

So that it will register it with https or http. That should do the trick.

You can also view this article in stackoverflow: [Why do I have both HTTPS and HTTP links on site, need them all secure!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986616/why-do-i-have-both-https-and-http-links-on-site-need-them-all-secure)

Good luck!